# Qual a maneira recomendada de importar módulos?

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação, importação, pep8

Tenho duas classes no módulo, devo fazer a importação dos módulos antes de criar as classes ou importar antes de cada classe o que será utilizado nela.

Exemplos:

```
from teste import a
from outro_teste import b

class Class1(a):
    ...
class Class2(b):
    ...
```

ou

```
from teste import a
class Class1(a):
    ...

from outro_teste import b
class Class2(b):
```

Comment: Eu fiz umas modificações na sua pergunta que so meu ver mantem e a tornam mais atrativa para leitura mantendo a essência do seu questionamento, Caso não  tenha gostado das modificações você pode a qualquer momento desfazer essas modificações consultando o [histórico de edições da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/591471/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

### Onde resolver dúvidas ou questões sobre o estilo de escrita de código Python?

Em Python quando tiver dúvidas ou questões sobre o estilo de escrita de código a documentação a se consultada inicialmente é a [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008); cujo os autores são
Guido van Rossum, Barry Warsaw e Alyssa Coghlan; e em sua [introdução](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#introduction), o documento se descreve como fornecedor de **convenções** de codificação para o código Python que compreende a biblioteca padrão na distribuição principal do Python.
<sub>Note que no parágrafo a cima deixei grifado a palavra **convenções** pois no dicionário [Michaelis Online da Língua Portuguesa](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o/) a palavra convenção é definida como um *acordo, ajuste ou combinação sobre determinado assunto, atividade, etc* e no capítulo [Uma consistência tola é o fantasma das mentes pequenas](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) a própria PEP 8 fornece alguns motivos para ignorar uma determinada convenção.</sub>

### O que é uma PEP?

PEP significa Python Enhancement Proposal(Proposta de Aprimoramento Python) que são documentos que descrevem recursos propostos para a linguagem Python que podem ser encontrados no [Índice PEP](https://peps.python.org/#).

### O que diz a PEP 8 sobre importação de módulos?

Segue a tradução livre do capitulo sobre [Importações da PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports):

> **Importações**
>
> - As importações geralmente devem estar em linhas separadas:
>
>   ```
>   # Correto:   
>   import os   
>   import sys
>   ```
>
>   ```
>   # Errado:   
>   import sys, os
>   ```
>
>   Mas não há problema em escrever assim:
>
>   ```
>   # Correto:   
>   from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>   ```
> - As importações são sempre colocadas na parte superior do arquivo, logo após os comentários e as documentações do módulo e antes das
>   constantes e globais do módulo.   As importações devem ser agrupadas
>   na seguinte ordem:
>
>   1. Importações da biblioteca padrão.
>   2. Importações de terceiros relacionadas.
>   3. Importações específicas de aplicativos/bibliotecas locais.
>
>   Você deve colocar uma linha em branco entre cada grupo de
>   importações.
> - As importações absolutas são recomendadas, pois geralmente são mais legíveis e tendem a se comportar melhor (ou, pelo menos, a fornecer
>   mensagens de erro melhores) se o sistema de importação estiver
>   configurado incorretamente (como quando um diretório dentro de um
>   pacote acaba no `sys.path`):
>
>   ```
>   import mypkg.sibling 
>   from mypkg import sibling 
>   from mypkg.sibling import example
>   ```
>
>   No entanto, as importações relativas explícitas são uma alternativa aceitável às
>   importações absolutas, especialmente quando se lida com layouts de
>   pacotes complexos em que o uso de importações absolutas seria
>   desnecessariamente prolixo:
>
>   ```
>   from . import sibling   
>   from .sibling import example
>   ```
>
>   O código da biblioteca padrão deve evitar layouts de pacotes complexos e sempre usar importações absolutas.
> - Ao importar uma classe de um módulo que contém uma classe, geralmente não há problema em escrever isso:
>
>   ```
>   from myclass import MyClass   
>   from foo.bar.yourclass import YourClass
>   ```
>
>   Se essa grafia causar conflitos de nomes locais, escreva-os
>   explicitamente:
>
>   ```
>   import myclass   
>   import foo.bar.yourclass
>   ```
>
>   e use `myclass.MyClass` e `foo.bar.yourclass.YourClass`.
> - As importações curinga(`from <module> import *`) devem ser evitadas, pois elas não deixam claro quais nomes estão presentes no *namespace*,
>   confundindo os leitores e muitas ferramentas automatizadas. Há um caso
>   de uso defensável para uma importação curinga, que é republicar uma
>   interface interna como parte de uma API pública (por exemplo,
>   sobrescrever uma implementação Python pura de uma interface com as
>   definições de um módulo acelerador opcional e não se sabe exatamente
>   quais definições serão sobrescritas).   Ao republicar nomes dessa
>   forma, as diretrizes relativas a interfaces públicas e internas ainda
>   se aplicarão.

## Respondendo a pergunta:

Usaria o primeiro caso mantendo as importações na parte superior do arquivo:

```
from teste import a
from outro_teste import b

class Class1(a):
    ...
class Class2(b):
    ...
```

Porém usaria nomes mais descritivos de classes usando [CamelCase(CapWords)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camel-case?tab=Votes) conforme a PEP 8 convenciona em seu capitulo sobre [Identificadores de Classe](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names).